# Отслеживание загрузки файла из другого процесса C#

Tags: c#, p2p, torrent

Добрый день. Пытаюсь написать Торрент апдейтер для приложения. Торрент клиент является консольным приложением который поднимается в основном приложении через
`Process myProcess = new Process();`

Когда встал вопрос работы с прогресс баром, я зашел в тупик.

**Суть вопроса:** Возможно ли отследить загрузку файла с консольного приложения и при надобности (если это также возможно) имена скачиваемых файлов.

Заранее прошу прощения за глупый вопрос.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5 выбираете любой удобный способ

Comment: Торрент клиент, это ваше приложение, или чужое?

Comment: Торрент клиент написан на базе monotorrent и не сильно отличается от sample клиента. Просто множество попыток перевести его на wpf приложение заканчивались крахом.

Comment: Значит у вас есть вся инфа, нужно только ее передать и принять